# Is it possible to rent a Volkswagen T1/T2 in Iceland?

Tags: car-rentals, iceland

I'm considering renting a van for my upcoming trip in Iceland and it would be awesome if it was possible to rent a [Volkswagen T1/T2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Type_2) there. Despite all my searching, it looks like there is no rental company offering such service.

Is it possible to rent a VW T1/T2 in Iceland?

Comment: I think the chances are very slim in finding one. I guess it's because there are very little (none?) volkswagen T1/T2 vans in Iceland. I base this guess on a search of [an Icelandic second hand car site](http://www.bilasolur.is/Section.aspx?s=1). If they would exist there I would expect to see at least someone offering one for sale. Of course this was a quick search and I might be mistaken.

Comment: You know there is ferry to iceland? http://www.smyrilline.com/ you could drive your own t1/t2

Comment: Just for the fact that the T1/T2 are by today's standard antique cars I would assume that this is next to impossible. Unless you find a private person who owns one and rents it out to you.

Comment: I know it's hard, that's why I'm asking it here :-)

Comment: Maybe you could find an Icelandic old timers forum and see if someone has one and is willing to rent it out? My google skills didn't show up anything though except for a bunch of [Dutch guys who did a tour with their own old time VW's](http://www.northsailing.is/news/nr/2782/volkswagen-oldtimers/).

Comment: Are you planning to venture into the highlands at all? Because then a 4x4 vehicle is basically a must. Even if you're not using any of the [F-roads](http://sadcars.com/en/read/2012/03/12/how-to-drive-on-f-roads-in-the-highlands-of-iceland), gravel roads are very common and I doubt they'd be much fun in a VW T1/T2.

Comment: With the VW I'd only go on the ring road.

Comment: I guess you are aware that VW T1/T2 are classic cars and for one in a good shape you have to pay a lot (~30'000$ -50'000$). Even if you drive only the ring road, you're gonna hit some gravel roads (well gravel is nearly everywhere). I guess after several weeks you have to repaint some parts (fender, bumper, etc.) to prevent rust. So I guess the easiest way is to buy one for example in Europe and take the ferry --> http://www.directferries.co.uk/iceland.htm It's about 2000$ - 2500$ for a return ticket

Comment: @Mathias any chance you could write that as an answer?

Comment: @MarkMayo that wouldn't be a good answer and sure as hell not a good reason to not to have a business of vintage car rental in a country where car rental is a huge business.

Comment: @Geeo I was wondering about that, but given he's providing a way to get one to Iceland, it's an alternative means of getting to drive a T1/2 around Iceland, even if it means taking it on a ferry. Was just a thought :/

Comment: @Geeo Your right it's not an answer, it's opportunity to this without renting a T1/T2 in Iceland. Imho Iceland is the wrong country to drive classic cars around.

Answer (score 3):

I have searched google and other search sites for quite sometime now, and it seems there is no car rental that offers T1/T2. I can safely say the answer to this question is a simple "**No**".

Answer (score 3):

I've searched repeatedly, and even contacted a couple of car rental companies in Iceland on twitter. The answer definitely seems to be no, or if not, very, very rare - rare enough that's it not possible to find.